# Why string cannot convert to other data type array except uint8 and int32?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

When I try to convert `string` to `[]int`, compile fail. and I found string can convert `to int32(rune)` and `uint8(byte)`.
This is my test code:

```
s1 := "abcd"
b1 := []byte(s1)
r1 := []rune(s1)
i1 := []int8(s1) //error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is because the language specification does not allow it.

The allowed conversions for non-constant values: [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - `x` is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to `T`.
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` have [identical underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` are pointer types that are not [defined types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), and their pointer base types have identical underlying types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are both integer or floating point types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are both complex types.
> - `x` is an integer or a slice of bytes or runes and `T` is a string type.
> - **`x` is a string and `T` is a slice of bytes or runes.**

The longer answer is:

[Spec: Conversions: Conversions to and from a string type:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> 1. Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to `"\uFFFD"`.
> 2. Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose successive bytes are the elements of the slice.
> 3. Converting a slice of runes to a string type yields a string that is the concatenation of the individual rune values converted to strings.
> 4. **Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.**
> 5. **Converting a value of a string type to a slice of runes type yields a slice containing the individual Unicode code points of the string.**

Converting a `string` to `[]byte` is "useful" because that is the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the text, this is exactly how Go stores strings in memory, and this is usually the data you should store / transmit in order to deliver a `string` over byte-streams (such as [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)), and similarly, this is what you can get out of an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader).

Converting a `string` to `[]rune` is also useful, it result in the characters (runes) of the text, so you can easily inspect / operate on the characters of a `string` (which is often needed in real-life applications).

Converting a `string` to `[]int8` is not so much useful given that byte-streams operate on `byte`s (which is an alias to `uint8`, not `int8`). If in a specific case you need a `[]int8` from a `string`, you can write your custom converter (which would most likely convert the individual bytes of the string to `int8` values).

Answer (score 0):

from the go documentation:

string is the set of all strings of 8-bit bytes, conventionally but not
necessarily representing UTF-8-encoded text. A string may be empty, but
not nil. Values of string type are immutable.

so a string is the same as []uint8

that is why you can convert it to rune and uint8